# Phase portrait of nonlinear oscillator system ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given the system of ODE: $\ x' = y$, $\ y' = -f(x)$ where $f: R\rightarrow R$ is Lipschitz continuous. Let $F: R\rightarrow R$ be any antiderivative of $f$, and let $\ H(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{2} + F(x)$. Describe how to find the phase portraits of this nonlinear system, given that for any solution $\alpha: I\rightarrow R$, $H(\alpha(t)) = C$ $\ \forall\ t\in I$.

**My attempt:** I was able to show that for any solution $\alpha: I\rightarrow R$, $H(\alpha(t)) = C$ $\ \forall\ t\in I$. Then I considered the level set of the solutions $(x(t), y(t))$ such that $H(x,y) = C$. Differentiating both sides w.r.t $\ t$, I get: $yy' + f = 0$, or $\ f(1-y) = 0$ (since $\ f$ is Lipschitz continuous function). This implies $\ f = 0$ or $\ y(t) = 1$.

Thus, $(x,y) =  C(t, 1)$. So the phase portrait is a horizontal line $y=C$ for any constant C.

Can anyone please help verify my solution above, and correct my mistake(s) if any? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: My proof of $H(\alpha(t)) = C$ is following: we need to show $\frac{dH}{dt} = 0$, or $\frac{dH}{dt} = \frac{2y}{2}\frac{dy}{dt} + F'(x)\frac{dx}{dt}$. Since $F'(x) = f(x)$ as F is an anti-derivative of $f$, and using the two equations, we get:  $\frac{dH}{dt} = -yf(x) + f(x)y = 0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: think about the level sets of H

Comment: @MrSlunk: Thank you for your hint. I did think about the level sets of $H$, which would be in the form of $\frac{y^2}{2} + F(x) = C$. But we don't really know $F$, so how can we know the form of the phase portrait? Btw, can you check if my proof for the $H(\alpha(t)) = C$ is correct?

Comment: The second proof is correct. The initial proof had a typo in differentiation of $H(x, y) = C$ which lead to your confusion. You can mention some qualitative properties of phase portrait of such system, but of course you can't say anything concrete while $F(x)$ is unknown.

Comment: @Evgeny:thanks so much. May you please clarify on those qualitative properties for this system based on $H(x, y)$? Like the level sets of $H(x, y)$ has what kind of peoperties?

Comment: The equilibria of this system coincide with critical points of $H(x,y)$. If $H(x,y)$ is generic (critical points have non-degenerate Hessian; in this case it's equivalent to $F(x)$ having only simple zeros) then minima of $H(x,y)$ correspond to center equilibria and maxima of $H(x,y)$ correspond to saddles. (The fact that this system always has center at minima of $H(x,y)$ could be deduced from Morse theorem.) Separatrices of saddle are contained in the same level set as saddle itself. This could be easily used to detect heteroclinic or homoclinic orbits.

Comment: Also, this integral of system is not just an ordinary integral -- it's Hamiltonian :) and this is a Hamiltonian system on plane. There's a plenty of theory about them.

Comment: @Evgeny: great observation! You're definitely correct that this is Hamiltonian system. As I tried for different functions $f(x)$, I got very weird phase portraits. My question is how do we describe the shape of these phase portraits in general, or at least if they follow heteroclinic or homoclinic orbits? I got different phase portraits with different initial conditions (http://onlinesciencetools.com/tools/phaseportrait?dx=y&dy=-1%2Bx%5E2&x0=-1&y0=-2). What you said about the minima and maxima of $H(x,y)$ were correct, and it cannot have equilibrium as sinks or sources.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand your question about shape in general. Of course, this system is quite specific even in general form, there is one more feature: it always has symmetry $(x, y) \mapsto (x, -y)$.

Comment: @Evgeny: sorry for confusing you:( my question was: I want to describe the shape of a phase portrait of this system (e.g: look like a donut, a butterfly's wing, a parabola/hyperbola, etc).. so far I haven't been able to realize the specific pattern for a general shape of the solution $(x,y)$ regardless of the function $F$, so I doubt there is one?

Comment: I really doubt that there is a pattern :) But take a look at Reeb graphs (start from Wikipedia). As far as I remember they could be quite useful in some cases of classifying and describing Hamiltonians (and not only them).

Comment: @Evgeny: I took a look at Reeb graph and its definition. Sounds useful, but wonder if you can clarify on what you meant with "the system is quite specific in general form?" And I don't see why we need Lipschitz condition on $f$. Any thoughts for this?

Comment: 1) I meant that it's not an arbitrary conservative or Hamiltonian system and that it posesses additional symmetry. Nothing besides that :) 2) Haven't thought about this yet. But seems to be standard precaution for existence and uniqueness theorem to be applied here.